# javascript add relative path to all links dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a html file to prepend and replace string.

for example, if my url for css file,

```
<link href="/srsstore/store/-1/common/components/cbsassets/styles/iPhone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And url for image file,

```
<img src="/s/store/-1/ProductizedWidgets/transparent.png" width="1px" height="1px"/>
```

Also, for background image

```
<div style="background-color: #e45600;background-image: url(/s/store/4812610/no_preview.gif);background-repeat:repeat-x;font-weight:bold;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;color:#FFFFFF></div>
```

and I want to prepend "domain.com" to these urls. How do i search and replace a string dynamically using javascript.

The content is getting from this url:

http://euroleagueiphone.mo2do.net/s/31653/Home?ebbLinkIndex=0&backTitle=Home&iPhoneMode=app&debugRender=true&appVersion=2.2&engineVersion=1.3

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Actually the html page is in the XML format, so that i need to parse and create HTML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var domain = 'YOUR_DOMAIN';

    // For images        
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].setAttribute("src",domain + imgs[i].getAttribute("src"));
    }

    // For CSS files
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        links[i].setAttribute("href",domain + links[i].getAttribute("href"));
    }
};
```

**Edit:**

For the divs add the following code to the above:

```
// For CSS files
var styleProp = 'background-image';
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].currentStyle) {
        divs[i].style['styleProp'] = domain + divs[i].currentStyle[styleProp];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        divs[i].style['styleProp'] = domain + document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(divs[i],null)
                                .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    }
}
```

You can get help form [Get Styles](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).

Comment: And also containing the background image, <div style="background-color: #e45600;background-image: url(/s/store/4812610/no_preview.gif);background-repeat:repeat-x;font-weight:bold;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;color:#FFFFFF></div>

Comment: Does all the divs have property `background-image`?

Comment: But i will suggest you to give the absolute path when you write `HTML` code, because different browsers behave differently after rendering an element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find all the a's and img's in your code, loop through them, get the current attribute value (whether src or href), prepend your domain to it, and then set the attribute value.  I haven't tested this, but this is the general idea:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].setAttribute("href","domain.com" + links[i].getAttribute("href"));
}

for (i=0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i].setAttribute("src","domain.com" + images[i].getAttribute("src"));
}
```

Comment: Hi, the content is getting from this url: http://euroleagueiphone.mo2do.net/s/31653/Home?ebbLinkIndex=0&backTitle=Home&iPhoneMode=app&debugRender=true&appVersion=2.2&engineVersion=1.3

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function(){
    $e = $(this);
    $e.attr("src","http://example.com" + $e.attr("src"));
})

$("link").each(function(){
    $e = $(this);
    $e.attr("href","http://example.com" + $e.attr("href"));
})
```

Use jquery